# Seo битрикс теги

Tags: битрикс, seo

Для чего нужен последний пункт "теги"? Что это и как они выглядят, можно пример привести.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пример: `#сказочноебали`

Comment: А для чего он? Соц сети или ещё что?

Comment: Для того же самого, для чего вы поставили два тега под этим вопросом ;)

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря возможностям модуля Поиск индексирование происходит не только по тексту, но и по тегам, если они, конечно, указаны.

Достаточно часто бывает очень удобно использовать поочередно оба поисковых механизма. Например, сначала отобрать страницы по нужному тегу, а потом вести поиск с помощью поискового индекса, в отобранных по тегам результатах.

Теги - это темы информационного сообщения. Под информационным сообщением понимается многое: элемент инфоблока, сообщение в форуме или блоге, теги фотографий и так далее.
На данный момент ввод тегов возможен в статических страницах, элементах информационных блоков, в блогах и форумах. Формат ввода тегов: через запятую и пробел.
[image: Картинка из источника]

[Источник](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=2067)

Answer (score 0):

Мета-теги (от англ. «meta tags») используются для того, чтобы структурировать сопроводительные данные о странице. Они рассчитаны исключительно на роботов, браузеры, специализированное ПО, чтобы те корректно «прочли» и обработали представленную информацию. Мета-данные располагаются в директиве HEAD наряду со скриптами, стилями и линками (см. скриншот ниже).
[image: скриншот]
[Источник](https://blog.promopult.ru/seo/vazhnye-meta-tegi-dlya-seo-optimizacii-sajta.html)

Comment: Речь не о том.... Прочитайте вопрос внимательно